# How to make a datagrid see edits in a control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a user control that I am using to populate a datagrid.

I would like the user to be able to add items by editing the empty row at the bottom. (This is why I am using a datagrid rather than an itemscontrol)  However the datagrid does not realise that the last item is edited unless the user clicks the background of the control.  I would like the new item to be added when the user makes changes on the properties that the control exposes.

XAML of the control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ControlTest.MyControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ControlTest"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="300"
         DataContext="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         >
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=p1, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
           Width="300"
           Height="30"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DropDownValues,
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                AncestorType=local:MyControl}}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=p2, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              Height="30"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

cs:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    private static readonly DependencyProperty DropDownValuesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "DropDownValues", 
        typeof(List<String>),
        typeof(MyControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new List<String>()
        ));
    public List<String> DropDownValues
    {
        get
        {
            return (List<String>)GetValue(DropDownValuesProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(DropDownValuesProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }        
}
```

DataGrid XAML

```
    <DataGrid 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding objs, Mode=TwoWay}" 
        HeadersVisibility="None"
        Margin="0,0,0.4,0"
        CanUserAddRows="True"
        >
        <DataGrid.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </DataGrid.ItemsPanel>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="300">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="local:Measure">
                        <local:MyControl 
                            DataContext="{Binding ., Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            DropDownValues=
                        "{Binding DataContext.list, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                            Width="300"
                        />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Can I make this work, and/or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by : datagrid does not realise that the last item is edited unless the user clicks the background of the control. I mean what is the default behavior???

Comment: @Vishal Default behavior without the control is that the new object gets added once the fields on it loses focus.  This is somewhat similar to what I observe when I have a control, but the datagrid does not understand that the cell has focus when it's one of the controls inside the controls that I edit - so no new item gets added until I click the background of the control.

Comment: How do you know the Datagrid isn't aware that the last item has been edited?  Are you adding to `Items` Directly or to `objs`?

Comment: @M312V Not sure what you are asking.  When the datagrid sees that the new item should be comitted it gets added to objs, since that is what the datagrid is bound to.  However I am unable to get that event to fire in responce to actions taken on the input boxes in the control. - It only fires if the user first double click the background in the control and then clicks outside the control.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest you a different way of doing that:

set `CanUserAddRows=false` on your DataGrid and then manually add rows to the `ObservableCollection<Something>` to which your DataGrid is bound to.

**OR**

If you are still interested in the approach that you follow:

In your xaml file:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" CellEditEnding="DataGrid_CellEditEnding" .....>
    <!--Some Code-->
</DataGrid>
```

Then in the Code-Behind:

```
private void DataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    myDataGrid.CommitEdit();
}
```

If you don't understand anything then feel free to ask.

**Update**

If you are following the same approach:

In your DataGrid's Beginning edit event you can try:

```
private void DataGrid_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
{
    if ((selectedRow as DataGridRow).Item.ToString() != "{NewItemPlaceholder}")
    {
        //Here you can add the code to add new item. I don't know how but you should figure out a way
    }
}
```

*Note:* The code mentioned above is not tested.

I would also suggest you :

Not to use DataGrid. Instead use ListBox. Because, you are trying to add some data. At this time you never need sorting, searching and column-reordering fascilities. In such scenario, ListBox is useful as it is light-weight control than datagrid. I have a sample here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5WyqSALui0bTXFGZWxQUWVRdkU

Comment: Setting CommitEdit on CellEditEnding did not cause a new item to be created when I make changes in the fields in the control.  It does cause a stackoverflow exception when I double click the background of the control.

Comment: Is there a way to manually add the rows without making the control aware of the collection?

Comment: Originally implemented with ListBox.  Changed to DataGrid because ListBox does not have built in support for new items.  BeginEdit has exactly the same problem as the other events.  The control is opaque to the datagrid;

Comment: @Taemyr then why are you relying on built in support for new items? I mean just set CanUserAddRows to false. And then do everything manually on viewmodel to get more control on what and how the dataGrid displays???

Comment: Because in general it's preferable to use existing methods rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Taemyr Yes you are right about that, but you don't have more control over that. In general, where no extra facilities are needed its a good practice to use existing methods. But when you need a facility that is not available or very hard to achieve, you must do it manually. I believe so.

Answer (score 1):

Is the problem that the UI is not being notified of changes to the objs collection? What I would do is try setting up whatever view model that contains objs to make objs an observable collection. I would also ensure that whatever objs is an observable collection of implements INotifyPropertyChanged and that properties p1 and p2 both fire OnPorpertyChanged when they are set.

```
public ObservableCollection<YourObject> objs
```

and

```
public class YourObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string Name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Name));
        }
    }

    private string _p1;
    public string p1
    {
        get { return _p1; }
        set
        {
            if (_p1 != value)
            {
                _p1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("p1");
            }
        }
    }
    private string _p2;
    public string p2
    {
        get { return _p2; }
        set
        {
            if (_p2 != value)
            {
                _p2 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("p2");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that new items are not added to the collection when I make changes in the item in the control.  -  If I make changes to the collection from outside the datagrid gets upgraded, however to cause the datagrid to add an item to the collection I have to click the background of the control - I would like the new item to be created and added when I start to edit the items in the control.

Comment: And the collection is already an observablecollection of classes that implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Try InvalidateArrange and/or InvalidateMeasure.